# how to hide element on blur, unless that element is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set up an auto-complete search form with jQuery.
I would like to hide the search results div when the field isn't focused, however if someone tries to click a link within the results, they are unable to since it instantly becomes hidden, since the search field lost focus.
Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input type='search' id='search' placeholder='search' />
</form>
<div id='search-results' style='display:none'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Example Result</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  query = $(this).val();
  if(query.length > 2) {
    $("#search-results").html(get_search_results(query)).show();
  } else {
    $("#search-results").hide();
  }
});

$("#search").focus(function() {
  if($(this).val().length > 2) {
    $("#search-results").show();
  }
}); 

$("#search").blur(function() {
  $("#search-results").hide(); //makes it impossible to click results
});
```

How can I accomplish hiding the results when not in use, but still have them be clickable?

Comment: It should work as blur is called when your input element has lost focus

Comment: ANd how should you click them if they are invisible ?

Comment: @lukas.pukenis the issue is that when a user clicks the result, the input loses focus, so the result link is hidden, so the user cant click it.

Comment: Maybe you should wrap everything in <div id="wrapper" and hide when it loses focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend setting a function to check if the mouse is over the search-results div.
Like so.

```
// Have a global variable
var hovered = false;
```

Then have a function that changes it on rollover

```
$("#search-results").bind("mouseover",function() {
    hovered = true;
}).bind("mouseout",function() {
    hovered = false;
});
```

then in your function you check if the variable is true

```
$("#search").blur(function() {
    if(!hovered) {
        $("#search-results").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#search-results").bind("mouseup",function() {
            $("#search-results").hide();
        })
    }
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Using a global variable to store information to be checked is always a dangerous idea.

Comment: Can you explain why?  I know this is an old question, but I'm really curious as to why global variables are bad.

Comment: If another script also had a `hovered` variable, it could do undesirable things since both scripts would be modifying the same value. This is easily fixed by wrapping all of the above in a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, like:

```
$('#search').data("wait_a_bit", false);
$("#search").blur(function()
{
    if (!$(this).data("wait_a_bit"))
       $("#search-results").hide();
});

$("#search-results").mousedown(function() {
    $("#search").data("wait_a_bit", true);
});

$("#search-results").bind("mouseup mouseleave", function() {
    if ($("#search").data("wait_a_bit"))
    {
        $("#search").data("wait_a_bit", false);
       $("#search-results").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the elements within your form.
To something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <form>
      <input type='search' id='search' placeholder='search' />
    </form>
    <div id='search-results' style='display:none'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Example Result</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

And change your hide code to:

```
$("#search").mouseout(function() {
  $("#search-results").hide(); //makes it impossible to click results
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to simply set a timeout for your blur event:

```
$("#search").blur(function() {
    window.timeout = setTimeout(''+
    '$("#search-results").hide();'+
    'clearTimeout(window.timeout);'+
    'delete window.timeout;'+
    '',150); //makes it impossible to click results
});
```

Here it is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/R4ufB/
You can click on a result .. a string is written in the console ... and the results are hidden.

Furthermore, if you neeed that your link doesn't disappear after clicking on it, just add a checking method to its onclick event, for example by adding a class to the wrapper 'search-results' div:

```
<a href='#' onclick="$('#search-results').addClass('clicked');console.log('clicked');">Example Result</a>
```

or put it where you like with jQuery:

```
... js part ...
$('.results').click(function()
{
    $('#search-results').addClass('clicked');
    console.log('clicked');
});

... html part ...
<a href='#' class="results">Example Result</a>
```

and then change the above code to:

```
$("#search").blur(function() {
    window.timeout = setTimeout(''+
    'if (!$("#search-results").hasClass("clicked"))'+
    '    $("#search-results").hide();'+
    'clearTimeout(window.timeout);'+
    'delete window.timeout;'+
    '',150); //makes it impossible to click results
});
```

Here it is a working demo of that one too: 
http://jsfiddle.net/awsVd/
You click an a result .. a string is written in the console .. and the results are not hidden.